# Word for describing a predominant orientation for an academic degree

Tags: word-request

When faced with the task of translating academic documents, I often encounter difficulties with translating the dominant of a field of study. Let me take an example.

> Your studies were about cooking in general. In the last year, you specialized in cooking pastas. At the end of the last year, on your diploma, you'll get :
>   ***Bachelor in cooking, _____ (specialty ? dominant ? mention ?) pastas***.

I want to express the fact that you know how to cook, however your knowledge of pasta is predominant over the general knowledge you have acquired. I have put some words I have thought of, but I am uncertain if they fit the situation I described.

If needed, here are a few more similar examples where the word I look for is missing :

Master of Art, ______ Photography

B.Sc. Biology, ______ Stem cells and bioethics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many universities use the term **concentration** - see [definition 1b](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concentration):

> an academic major or area of focus within a major

It may not always appear in the actual degree paperwork, so it won't be capitalized in full sentences.

> I have a BS in Physics, with a concentration in electro-optics.

Comment: So you can say either : Master of Art, Major Photography ? Or even : Master of Art, Concentration Photography ?

Comment: "Master of Fine Arts, Concentration in Photography" = Fine Arts is the major.  "MA in Photography" = Photography is the major (and "MA" stands for Master of Arts).  Comparing to your B.Sc. Biology, Biology is the major, stem cells etc. is the concentration

Comment: I almost got it wrong then, thanks for clarifying !